# What GUI tool can I use to connect to Postgres RDS that is not publicly accessible

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

What GUI tool can I use to connect to Postgres RDS that is not publicly accessible?  I have used pgAdmin earlier when the db was open but now that the RDS is not publicly accessible, is there a GUI-based tool that I can use to connect?  Thanks.

Comment: Define '...not publicly accessible...'? If the database is reachable, in that it can be connected to, I would expect any client to be usable.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - the RDS setting 'Publicly accessible' is set to No.  Also, in the inbound security rules of the RDS security group - only EC2 instance and my ip are allowed

Comment: there are ways you can use aws to host pgadmin on the same network as your rds instance

Comment: So as long as you are connecting from your IP  everything should work as before.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Any articles that you can refer me to please?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - that's what I thought but the connection is timing out.  As soon as I set the public access to yes, I am able to connect to pgAdmin.  What am I missing?

Comment: Aah, from here [Publicly accessible](https://www.intelligentdiscovery.io/controls/rds/aws-rds-publicly-accessible), setting 'Publicly accessible' to NO means there is no external IP set for the database. That is why you are timing out. Looks like you can only connect from devices in the VPC.

Answer (score 3):

The typical way to connect to a 'private' RDS database is to use **SSH with Port Forwarding** to connect to a 'Bastion Server', which is an Amazon EC2 instance that is in a public subnet in the same VPC as the database. For example:

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4 -L 5000:<RDS-DOMAIN-NAME>:5432
```

You can then connect your SQL Client to `localhost:5000` (or whatever number you configured), which will be directed across the SSH connection, where the Bastion Server will forward the request to the database.

For good security, restrict the Security Group on the Bastion Server so that it only accepts SSH connections from your own IP address.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have set it to not publicly accessible, that takes priority over the inbound security rules.  So you can't connect directly from your own IP address, only from EC2 and other aws resources.

The simplest option would be to set it back to publicly accessible. Then access would be controlled by the need both to know the password, and to come from your whitelisted IP address. I would think those two independent layers of protection are adequate.  But there are others, which all involve running a EC2 machine to bridge from your IP to the RDS host.

One is to set up an SSH tunnel from your machine to the EC2 host with that being set up to allow forwarding the 5432 port to RDS host.  You can either set this up yourself by calling ssh yourself from your local machines command line and then pointing your local pgAdmin to the local port you chose.  Or you can have pgAdmin set up the tunnel for you.  It has a SSH tab in the server properties dialog box for doing so.  Other GUIs can also be used on either of these two ways (i know DBeaver can, i assume others as well.)

Another way would be to set up an EC2 host with a windowing system and install your favorite GUI on it, then run that GUI on EC2 but controlled from and displayed on your local machine with something like RDP or xterm.

Finally you could install pgAdmin4 in 'server mode' on EC2.  Then you would run your favorite web browser locally, and point it's address bar at the EC2 host at the chosen port, like 80 or 8080 or 8000, but you could also choose some more obscure number. You would need to open that port in the security group of course.  I don't if any popular gui besides pgAdmin4 supports this mode.